# Вывод значений на экран из нового потока JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx

Создаю новый поток и из него мне необходимо вывести значение t1 в Label

```
  public void Seconds(){
    new Thread(() -> {
        finish.set(true);
        while (finish.get()){
            a1++;
            t1 = Integer.toString(a1);
            Label.setText(t1);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(999);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Но вместо вывода значений получаю ошибку, что это не возможно. Как в таком случае вывести необходимое значение на экран? Через System.out.println(t1); все работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  public void Seconds(){
    new Thread(() -> {
        finish.set(true);
        while (finish.get()){
            a1++;
            t1 = Integer.toString(a1);
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
               Label.setText(t1);
            }
            });
            try {
                Thread.sleep(999);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Plutform.runLater выполняет код в потоке пользовательского интерфейса. Любые изменения в интерфейсе необходимо проводить через него

Comment: Учитывая то что скорее всего это Java8 можно вместо реализации Runnable засунуть лямбду и сократить код Platform.runLater(()->Label.setText(t1))